# How to implement Enum in SpringBoot with neo4j Rx?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have an entity class with an enumeration class, while I am trying to insert data then it shows me a **conversion error**. What is the best and easiest way to implement it?

```
enum class Vehicle {
    Bike,
    Bicycle
}

class VehicleTemplate{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id:Long?=null

    var model:String?=null

    var type:Vehicle?=null
}

interface VehicleTemplateInf : ReactiveNeo4jRepository< VehicleTemplate,Long>

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product/category/")
class CrtProductCategory {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var vehicleTemplateInf: VehicleTemplateInf

    @PutMapping("add")
    fun addCategory(@RequestBody vehicleTemplate: VehicleTemplate?): Mono< VehicleTemplate > {
        return  vehicleTemplateInf(vehicleTemplate!!)
    }
}
```

**Displayed Error**

```
"No converter found capable of converting from type [Product.Vehicle] to type [org.neo4j.driver.Value]"
```

I have used this dependencies

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rx-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you are facing. Can you share the project somewhere or at least add the JSON(?) data request?

Comment: Thank you @meistermeier . Here it is, { "model": "CB150R", "type": "Bike" }

Comment: You spotted an interesting bug in the combination of Spring Boot 2.3 and SDN/RX 1.1.0. With the just released 1.1.1 version of SDN/RX this should work now as intended.